# Pass base 64 to input value

Tags: javascript, file, input, drag-and-drop, filereader

I want to create a drag and drop input for a picture which is then processed by the server-side. JavaScript for the drag and drop is getting the file information in base64 format which is not passing into the input value.

```
dropArea.addEventListener("drop", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
        let fileType = file.type;
        let valid = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpeg"];
        if (valid.includes(fileType)) {
            let fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = () => {
                let fileURL = fileReader.result;
                input.value = fileURL;
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            dropArea.classList.remove('active');
        }
    })
```

How can I convert base64 in a format which will pass in the input value?

Comment: Why don't you just send the file itself in the form?

Comment: It isn't working. It needs a file URL which I am not being able to convert it into.

Comment: You need a file url oder data url? Currently you will get a data url. A base64 encoded string representation like `data:image/jpeg;base64,[baseb64 string]`. And this value you can not set as the value of a input field?